# Finding Overlap date ranges between startdate and enddate in couch Db or cloudant

Tags: couchdb, view, cloudant

Hello I am building a reservation app using database as couchDb. I have several reservation documents and each of them has roomId, start date and end date.

Now when user creates a meeting request with roomId, start date and end date, I need to search for overlaps time ranges between the start time and endtime in the existing reservations and create a reservations only when there is no conflict. Along with this I also need to check for roomid.

The requirement is similar to [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap).

I had created a view on my couch db emitting three keys:

```
function (doc) {  
    if (doc.type == "reservation") {  
         emit([doc.roomid, doc.startTime, doc.endTime], doc);  
    }
}
```

I did try creating something like

```
?startkey=["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", ""]&endkey=["\ufff0", "1971-01-01T00:00:00Z"]
```

However I am not really getting how to compound query the view to find range of date along with the roomid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Cloudant Query](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query) and specify the `(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)` search condition that's outlined in the referenced answer.

**Create an index**

Send a `POST` request to the `_index` endpoint, passing the following JSON data structure as payload.

```
  POST https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DATABASE/_index HTTP/1.1

 {
  "index": {
   "fields": [
     { "name":"startTime",
       "type":"string"
     }, 
     { 
       "name":"endTime",
       "type":"string"
     }, 
     { 
       "name":"roomid",
       "type":"string"
     } 
   ]
  },
  "type": "text"
 }
```

**Query the index**

Send a `POST` request to the `_find` endpoint, passing the following JSON data structure as payload.

```
  POST https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$HOST/$DATABASE/_find HTTP/1.1

  {
   "selector": {
    "startTime": {
      "$lte": "2017-03-06T15:00:00Z"
    },
    "endTime": {
      "$gte": "2017-03-06T14:00:00Z"
    },
    "roomid": {
      "$eq": "room 123"
    }
   }
  }
```

Replace the timestamp and room identifier values as needed. If the query returns at least one document you've encountered a booking conflict.

Comment: Thank you pointing me to this. I will try this one out and reach out if I need anything else.

Comment: This should also be available in couchdb 2.0+. I can't think of a way to arrive at the same operating using a single map-reduce, so thanks Mango!